# MySQL connection with Python through PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python, pythonanywhere

I want to connect to MySql database using Python through PythonAnywhere, without creating a Flask/Django application.

I have seemingly managed to connect through MySQLdb, using the code below, but I do not receive a response when I run the code. Any solutions?

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(
    host = "myuser.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com",
    user = "myuser",
    passwd = XXX,
    db = "myuser$db_name"
    )

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name")

for x in cursor:
    print(x)

cursor.close()
db.close()
```

Comment: How are you running this code, and what form of "response" are you expecting?

Comment: The print statement is not responding, for example

Answer (score 1):

You retrieve all rows in the table, without error.

```sql
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name")

for x in cursor:
    print(x)
```

Yet you see no output. This is normal for a table that contains zero rows.

Consider doing one or more INSERTs, and a COMMIT,
prior to the query.